# How can I prevent my hero from auto-attacking?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When I'm playing a hero with cloak like Nova, it takes a few seconds of not engaging in combat before I can cloak again.  During this time, I frequently find my hero happily shooting up any minions or structures that are nearby, resetting the cloak timer.  Most of the time, this isn't what I want to have happen.

I heard that the S key is supposed to cancel all actions, but I haven't had success with this.  I've sat uncloaked next to minions fighting minions while I spam the S key and Nova still shoots nearby enemies.  Many times moving around helps, but on occasion I find myself on a stealth mission in the enemy base and am unable to move without drawing fire from forts and towers.

How can I prevent my uncloaked hero from unloading on everything red in sight?

Comment: I haven't played HotS yet, but I know in League of Legends HOLDING the 's' key will prevent your character from auto-attacking.  This seems like something that could be common across all the games in the genre, so maybe try holding down the 's' key, instead of mashing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When playing Nova I usually just keep her moving a bit back and forth. This works without problems, just make sure you click a bit further than where you'd want her to go, so there's no moment she's idle waiting for input. Just turn in time by issuing the next command.

<kbd>S</kbd> will just make your character stop and possibly auto attack as you've noticed already.

Comment: I didn't put it in the question, but H does nothing for me.

Comment: @Troen Yeah, possible that key bind doesn't even exist. Wrote that from my mobile phone not having the game at hand right now. :)

Comment: Moving is how I do it, too.  Also, she won't auto-attack enemies that can't see her while she's cloaked, even if that cloak is due to bushes rather than her passive.  So you can idle in bushes until cloak deploys, if moving back and forth is too much work :D

Comment: There is no "Hold" command in HotS yet. This answer would be the correct one IMO if you remove that part.

Comment: Even if the H (hold position) keybind from was present in Heroes, it wouldn't stop Nova from attacking, only stop her from moving to acquire targets.  WC3 common campaign strat is to have Footmen in Defend stance *H*old position in a line and set Archers behind them.  The Footmen won't break formation to engage enemy melee, so the archers devastate while the enemy advances.  Once they hit the line, though, the Footmen still fight back;  when they break to flee, however, the Footmen don't chase.  The archers get their parting shots, though :D

Comment: @gatherer818 True, though this is most often a problem when I'm backdooring a Murky or Abathur and I'm using my decoy to distract the fort and moving would take me into the towers.  Often I just shoot back instead of recloaking in time. :(  I guess I can try spinning.

Comment: Alternatively, you can spam `S` if you do not wish to move.

Comment: Looks like the `H` key now functions as a "hold fire" command as well: http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/20099322/heroes-of-the-storm-patch-notes-april-19-2016-4-19-2016#User_Interface

Answer (score 2):

Hold down your right mouse button and just keep dragging it around to continually move. The great thing about this is no accidental attack clicks.